# Django template rendering does not display my data

Tags: django

I just can't solve my problem, don't see where/what do i wrong. Here is my urls.py:

```
from accounts.views import AccountList as account_views
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^account/(?P<uuid>[\w-]+)/', account_views.account_detail, name='account_detail'),
]
```

Here is my model

```
class Account(models.Model):
    uuid = ShortUUIDField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    desc = models.TextField(blank=True)
    address_one = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address_two = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,)
    created_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Here is my view

```
class AccountList(ListView):
    model = Account

    @login_required()
    def account_detail(request, uuid):

        account = Account.objects.get(uuid=uuid)
        if account.owner != request.user:
                return HttpResponseForbidden()
        variables = {
            'account': account,
        }

        return render(request, 'accounts/account_detail.html', variables)
```

Im tried to render it in my accaunt_detail template with following code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div id="content-container" class="container p-none">
        <div id="ad-container">
            <div id="gi-container" class="ad-container">
            <div class="row gi-body">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <h5 class="gi-sh">Description</h5>
                    <p>{{ account.desc }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <h5 class="gi-sh">Address</h5>
                    <p class="nm">{{ account.address_one }}</p>
                    <p class="nm">{{ account.address_two }}</p>
                    <p class="nm">{{ account.city}}, {{ account.state }}</p>
                    <p class="nm">{{ account.phone}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {# List Contacts #}
        {# List Communications #}
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

My base.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CRM Easy</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
    </header>
    <div id="site-wrapper">
        {% block content %}
            if you see this, something is wrong!
        {% endblock content %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But i get just empty Page. 
[image]

I do not get any errors, like everything works fine but the user details are not displayed. I have created ~15 users, so i have users in my database.

Comment: print something by manually entering some text in your template.

Comment: in my opinion you have some other issue. It should print **Description, Address** headers at least.

Comment: Have you migrated your new model?

Comment: Can you share base.html code?. I suspect block content is missing in base.html

Comment: You're right @umar-asghar, it doesn't output anythink :(. I putted some <p>Text</p> but didn't come any output. It means i have problem in my urls.py right?

Comment: yeah it can be or you are approaching to different url or different template.

Comment: My urls.py looks so: `from accounts import urls as account_urls` and then urlpatterns `re_path(r'^account/(?P<uuid>[\w-]+)/', include(account_urls)),` And in my included app url so: `from .views import AccountList urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^$',
        AccountList.account_detail, name='account_detail'
    ),
]`

Comment: Could you paste the url you are trying to access? And update the urls.py in the question? And also the base.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not at all how class-based views work. You can't define arbitrary methods and point to them from the URL conf; you always need to call the `as_view()` in the URL pattern, and the `dispatch()` method will call `get()` or `post()`.

However in this case you are not using any of the features of the class-based view, so there is absolutely no point using one. You should extract your `account_detail` method from that class and make it a standalone function, then point your URL pattern directly to that.

Comment: Thanks! I just did not carefully read the tutorial and added this function to the class https://ultimatedjango.com/learn-django/lessons/view-account-create-view/?trim=yes